# validation form : how to show error message all at one time for the blank input instead of one by one?

Tags: javascript

I want to validate my form, if any of the input field is blank, the error warning will show beside the blank input field. The error message must be comes out all at one time for the blank input, not show one by one. How to do this?

Below is my javascript code :

```
    function doValidate()
    {
        var x=document.forms["form"]["fullname"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
            {
            document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML="Full name is required!";
            return false;
            }

        var y=document.forms["form"]["uid"].value;
        if (y==null || y=="")
            {
            document.getElementById('error2').innerHTML="Username is required!";
            return false;
            }

        var z=document.forms["form"]["pwd"].value;
        if (z==null || z=="")
            {
            document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML="Password is required!";
            return false;
            }

        var a=document.forms["form"]["pwd2"].value;
        if (a==null || a=="")
            {
            document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML="Please re-enter your password!";
            return false;
            }

        var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        var pwd2 = document.getElementById("pwd2").value;
        if(pwd != pwd2){
            alert('Wrong confirm password!');
            return false;
        }

        var b=document.forms["form"]["role"].value;
        if (b==null || b=="Please select...")
            {
            document.getElementById('error5').innerHTML="Please select user role!";
            return false;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start your function with `var ok = true`, and in each `if`-block, instead of having `return false`, you should set `ok = false`. At the end, return `ok`.

Here's what that might look like:

```
function doValidate() {
    var ok = true;

    var form = document.forms.form;

    var fullname = form.fullname.value;
    if (fullname == null || fullname == "") {
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML = "Full name is required!";
        ok = false;
    }

    var uid = form.uid.value;
    if (uid == null || uid == "") {
        document.getElementById('error2').innerHTML = "Username is required!";
        ok = false;
    }

    var pwd = form.pwd.value;
    if (pwd == null || pwd == "") {
        document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = "Password is required!";
        ok = false;
    }

    var pwd2 = form.pwd2.value;
    if (pwd2 == null || pwd2 == "") {
        document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML = "Please re-enter your password!";
        ok = false;
    } else if (pwd != pwd2) {
        document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML = "Wrong confirm password!";
        ok = false;
    }

    var role = form.role.value;
    if (role == null || role == "Please select...") {
        document.getElementById('error5').innerHTML = "Please select user role!";
        ok = false;
    }

    return ok;
}
```

(I've taken the liberty of changing to a more consistent formatting style, improving some variable-names, simplifying some access patterns, and replacing an `alert` with an inline error message like the others.)

Comment: Thanks Ruakh you really made my day! :) It works perfectly now either using your code or my code! just adding the 'var ok = true' method. thank you so much!